# Is $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] the cause of redirect issues?

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have enabled vanity urls (user.domain.com).  When a session expires or somebody clears the cookies, the page would get redirected to user.domain.com which has the login page.  So, on all pages i am using the following code:

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) { header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]");}
```

2 of of 10 times i get a redirect error saying that the page is redirecting too many times.

Could this be the reason? And if it is what can i do to redirect in a way that won't cause such issues.

Thanks.

Login code:

```
<?php

 session_start(); 



  // Process the POST variables
  $username = $_SESSION["user_name"];
   //$password = $_POST["password"];


  // Set up the session variables
  $_SESSION["user_name"] = $username;

   $ugData = $_REQUEST['sub_name'];

 if($_POST){
  $_SESSION['user_name']=$_POST["user_name"];
  $_SESSION['password']=$_POST["password"];  
   }



   $secret = $info['password'];

//Checks if there is a login cookie

   if(isset($_COOKIE['ID_my_site']))


   //if there is, it logs you in and directes you to the members page

           { 
      $username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']; 

      $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT user_name, password FROM accounts WHERE user_name = '$username' and sub_name='$ugData'")or die(mysql_error());

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )) 



    {

        if (@ $info['password'] != $pass) 
        {

                    }

    else

        {

        header("Location: home.php");



        }

    }

        }


       //if the login form is submitted 

       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if form has been submitted



           // makes sure they filled it in

        if(!$_POST['user_name'] | !$_POST['password']) {

          die('You did not fill in a required field.');

            }

            // checks it against the database



          if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

    $_POST['user_name'] = addslashes($_POST['user_name']);


              }

$check = mysql_query("SELECT user_name,password FROM accounts 
    WHERE user_name = '".$_POST['user_name']."' 
    and sub_name='".$ugData."'")or die(mysql_error());



      //Gives error if user dosen't exist

      $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);

         if ($check2 == 0) {

     die('That user does not exist in our database. 
           <a href=add.php>Click Here to Register</a>');

            }

           while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))   

           {

        $_POST['password'] = md5($_POST['password']);
        $_POST['password'] = $_POST['password'];



      //gives error if the password is wrong



         if (@ $_POST['password'] != $info['password']) {

        die('Incorrect password, please try again');


                }

             else 

          { 


           // if login is ok then we add a cookie 

             $_POST['user_name'] = stripslashes($_POST['user_name']); 

              $hour = time() + 3600; 

                 setcookie(ID_my_site, $_POST['user_name'], $hour); 

                setcookie(Key_my_site, $_POST['password'], $hour);   



             //then redirect them to the members area 

        header("Location: home.php"); 

           } 

            } 

           } 

      else 

           {     





          ?>
```

Comment: OK.  NOw i see this as the reason being given for the error:       This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that redirecting to `http://yourserver/` means `http://yourserver/index.php`, then you should change the if to read

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name']) && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/index.php')
{
    header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]");
}
```

This will avoid endless redirects.

Comment: I tried that, but when the user goes to user.domain.com they will see the file log.php instead of index.php...  so not sure how to figure that in..

Comment: @AAA: change `/index.php` to `/log.php` in my answer, then.

Comment: Andrews solution seems to work but i will use yours to.  but like i said the issue happens once a day so i am going to have to sit it out to check.

Comment: see thets the problem it will redirect to user.domain.com/log.php  when it should simply redirect to user.domain.com

Comment: Hey this seems to be working.  I am going to keep this question open for a little longer just in case.

Comment: @Jon:  I am now getting this error using your script:  This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
    cookies.

Comment: OK new development.  I refreshed the error page after maybe 5 minutes.  then it redirected to the login page...

Answer (score 1):

The `header("Location: http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}");` isn't the problem per-say.

However, if you do have that code on your login page then yes, you'll just keep redirecting yourself to the home page because you won't be able to login.

Make sure that you do not redirect the user if he's on the login page.

**EDIT:** Try `header('Location: /');` Maybe you have some weird server issue which causes `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` do sometimes be null.

Comment: OK.  using the "/" works.  But the problem is that the issue doesn't happen all the time, so i am going to have to sit it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this with a die():

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) { header("Location: http://user.domain.com"); die();}
```

If url changes from user to user grab username from db first, and use it in redirection. Try something like:

```
...
$username = $row["username"];
...
```

and use it:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) { header("Location: http://".$username.".domain.com"); die();}
```

Comment: but wouldn't that leave the user at the redirect page because if it can't redirect the first time. it would give that error then??

Comment: With this code, there is no need to double redirection. It checks if user_name session set or not. If it is not set, redirects user to http://user.domain.com. It is so normal to get error about too many redirection because you are redirecting itself many times already. And also check whether did you started session at that page.

Comment: the thing is i am not using a fixed user.domain.com.  I am pulling the user from the domain by using the get function.

Comment: I think problem occurs because of getting url from browser URL. What I can't understand is why do you get url by GET method. Sooner or later, you have to grab username from db. Use it directly. Look at my update.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet.  I can do what you have recommended for all other pages.  But i still need to do it for the login page and the home page...

Comment: AAA sorry I didn't understand clearly. Is it possible to show us on your page? Could you give a sample URL?

Comment: Ok all other suggestions didn't work.  I am going to try yours tonight and test it out.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either.  let me post my login script.  maybe something with the cookies?

Comment: It seems to be OK. I think any user always stays in his own page. Ie. AAA.domain.com makes everything on AAA.domain.com and its subpages. You may try adding these to head of all pages: `if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) { $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; $username = explode(".",$ref); $username = end(explode("/",$username[0])); header("Location:".$username)."domain.com/login.php"); die(); }` You will get username from previous page URL and redirect it to users page.

Comment: I am still not sure about your need. Do you want a user to stay always on his own page but if his session or cookie deleted make a login again? There might be another solutions for that. We may be wrong with focusing on this way.

Comment: Hey right now i am testing Jon's solution it seems to be working for now.... i will keep this question open for a few more days.  thanks ahmet!

Comment: I just got another redirect error.  is it because of the login script??? Is there another script i can utilize???

Comment: Well, I suggest you to use http://usercake.com/ which is very simple/advanced user management system. I edited it suitable to my needs and really working great. That's enough to ask for isUserLoggedIn. You may use it.